# Pattern Matching on `Any` as 2-tuple?

Tags: scala, erasure

Given the following function:

```
scala> def foo(x: Any) = x match { 
     |   case _: (String, Int) => "foo"
     |   case _                => "bar"
     | }
```

I get the following compile-time warning:

```
<console>:8: warning: non-variable type argument String in type pattern (String, Int) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
         case _: (String, Int) => "foo"
                 ^
foo: (x: Any)String
```

My understanding of JVM erasure, namely for `List[T]`, is that, at run-time, the JVM does not know the type of `T`.

Please explain why the above `is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure` shows up for the attempt at pattern matching on the 2-tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element types are just type params of Tuple2.

But you can:

```
scala> (("hi",42): Any) match { case (_: String, _: Int) => }
```

Comment: thanks, Som-snytt. So when I try to pattern match directly on `_:(String, Int)`, why does the code even compile?

Comment: That checks instanceof Tuple2[String, Int], which is erased like List[Int]. The answer is a Tuple2 extractor followed by instanceof String and Int for the parts. (Actually it is smart enough to just instanceof Tuple2 first.)

Comment: interesting. so why is it `erased like List[Int]`?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? In this respect, it is the same as List.